# How to set keyboard focus to a representing parent element of a list

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, accessibility

I have a simple implementation on accessibility via keyboard input on a list of drop down menus, which I made using HTML/CSS and whose events are controlled via JS/jQuery.

The objective of accessibility via keyboard is like so:

1. Navigate the drop down menu elements by pressing on the **tab** key.
2. Press the **down arrow** key to open a focused menu.
3. Within such menu, pressing the **tab key** will help you navigate through the menu elements.
4. Within such menu, pressing the **esc** key will close the drop down menu.
5. Once the menu is closed, maintain keyboard focus upon the representing parent element of the menu.

Here is the [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/AGE/jzrko7cp/) I made as an example of a fully fledged implementation.

*The problem lies specifically in the jQuery code, the last statement is the one which is where I am trying to determine the solution to my problem (read below).*

*My problem:* 
How do I make it so that when the **esc** key is pressed to close the drop down menu; I am back to the drop down menu parent element which I first used to access the drop down menu elements via the **down arrow** key? The reason for this is that, in my implementation, if we exit the drop down menu we are effectively asking the user to tab their way to the element they where on.

That is the unintended behavior I am trying to fix by trying (and failing) to set the focus to the parent element I just visited.

Any help is very appreciated!

HTML

```
<ul class="menu">
    <li>
        <a href="#">Menu Elem</a>
        <div class="subMenu">
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Sub Menu Elem</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Sub Menu Elem</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Sub Menu Elem</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#">Menu Elem</a>
        <div class="subMenu">
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Sub Menu Elem</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Sub Menu Elem</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Sub Menu Elem</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#">Menu Elem</a>
        <div class="subMenu">
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Sub Menu Elem</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Sub Menu Elem</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Sub Menu Elem</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

CSS

```
.menu > li {
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: center;
    color: white;
    background-color: orange;
    width: 100px;
    height: 70px;
        position: fixed;
}

.menu > li:hover {
    cursor: pointer;
}
.menu > :nth-child(1) {
    left: 1px;
}
.menu > :nth-child(2){
    left: 102px;
}

.menu > :nth-child(3){
    left: 203px;
}
.menu > li > a {
    line-height: 70px;
}
.menu > li > .subMenu {
    display: none;
    width: 200px;
    margin-top: 1px;
    outline: 1px solid black;
}
.menu > li > .subMenu > ul > li {
    height: 100px;
    background-color: green;
    margin-left: -40px;
    line-height: 100px;
}
.menu > li > .subMenu > ul > li:hover {
    background-color: purple;
    cursor: pointer;
}
a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: white;
}
```

JS/jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var menuElem = $(".menu > li");

    $(menuElem).hover(function(){
        $(this).find(".subMenu").toggle();
    });

    $(menuElem).keydown(function(e) {
        // down arrow key
        if(e.keyCode === 40 && $(this).find(".subMenu").is(":hidden")){
            $(this).find(".subMenu").toggle();
        }
        // esc key
        else if(e.keyCode === 27 && $(this).find(".subMenu").is(":visible")){
            $(this).find(".subMenu").toggle();

            // ***** problematic code here *****
            // Need to target the <a> element, or the <li> element, or the <div>, or the <ul> element, not sure which one will work.
            // Currently: trying to get whichever element represents the selected menu, in the below case the anchor element

            $(menuElem).eq($(this).index()).find("a").addClass("selected");
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: You could try to set the focus to the parent's `a` element, by using `.focus()`

Comment: I am blown away that I skipped over that small of a detail, make it an answer @Philip

Comment: Just a minor comment on this design. #3 is not standard menu behavior. You typically navigate between the menu items using the up/down key and not tab.  You can see a pretty good section on keyboard interactions with a menu in the WAI-ARIA Authoring Practices - http://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria-practices/#menu

Comment: I completely agree with you @slugolicious, for anyone else reading on this question this is a design that is not of my making and I had to come up with a very specific screen reader solution to it. However if you find yourself interested in the ins and outs of the keypressed functionality, I do hope this serves as an example of how to work your way through any setup you have in mind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try to set the focus to the parent's `a` element, by using `.focus()`

Comment: Correct! Don't you love it when you waste time overlooking the smallest details? Well you shouldn't :)